# How to atomically set a value if a condition holds in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, compare-and-swap

I need to atomically assign `a = b` if condition `c` holds, and do not assign if the condition does not hold. Is there a way to do this in C/C++?

Clarification: I meant atomically "test and assign", rather than "atomically assign".

Comment: C or C++? Those are very different languages! Especially when it comes to atomics.

Comment: Does condition `c` depend on the current value of `a`? (Asking since you tagged with `compare-and-swap`.)

Comment: Define "atomic". Under what circumstances?

Comment: Atomically assign or atomically test and assign? It does say "atomically assign" but one could also think it is "atomically (assign a=b if condition c holds)".

Comment: don't go too far. find a spinlock implementation and use that

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Either C or C++ is fine.

Comment: @Thomas No. `c` does not depend on `a`. I just tagged it because I thought compare-and-swap might be useful.

Comment: Both languages have different implementations of atomic operations. Atomic operations in C are not compatible with the atomic operations in C++, and the opposite. What programming language are you actually using?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using C++.

Comment: @HansOlsson You are right. I should say "atomically test and assign". I am going to fix that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't a single operation that accomplishes what you require in general. The common case that *is* covered if is the case where your condition `c` tests if `a` is already set to some particular value. In this case, the operation you need is a compare-and-exchange, for example:

```
std::atomic<int> value;
...
int expected = 9;
bool result = std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&value, &expected, 10);
```

Here `value` is set to 10 only if the condition `value == 9` holds true, the whole operation being atomic.

If your condition doesn't take this form, then you would have to uses mutexes (or some other multiple-operation mechanism) to achieve atomicity.

Answer (score 1):

If `c` is some property of `a` itself, then compare-exchange atomic operations can solve your problems.  You have indicated in comments that this is not the case.

Failing that, wrap all access of `c` (anything that reads its state or modifies its state) and `a` within a locks of a common `std::mutex`.

Test `c` and assign to `a` within a lock of that `std::mutex`.

Failing that, write a single-threaded program.

Failing that, use OS-level APIs to suspend every thread in your process except yourself, then test `c` and possibly assign to `a`.  Note that this could see `c` or `a` in a state where it is half-written (ie, in an incoherant state), and with the thread suspension plan there really tends not to be a practical way to avoid it, unless both `c` and `a` are lock-free atomic themselves.

Note that this plan is extremely dangerous and fragile.

Failing that, describe your problem less abstractly and ask another question.  The odds are a less abstract version of your problem will have solutions is reasonable.